# How to change/suppress the file already exists message in NSSavePanel?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssavepanel

I use an NSSavePanel to ask users to indicate the file to which they want to save some information. If they choose an existing file I'd simply append the new information to the end. The issue is that OS X would give the following message:

> “new-file.txt” already exists. Do you want to replace it?

And I can't find a way to change this message. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you look into the validation methods of the delegate protocol? Never worked with this but it sounds like the validation message you see is the default implementation if a validation delegate method is not implemented.

Comment: I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: @saiwing I know that post is old. But did you find solution to this problem? I recently came across on the same problem

Comment: Nope, sorry. But I also haven't looked into this for years.